# Given Two Points, Find the coordinates of the point that is 1/7 of the way from Point 1 and Point 2

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a math problem here that says: given two points P(1,2,-1) and Q(3,0,2), find the coordinates of the point that is 1/7 of the way from P to Q. So so far I did 3-1, 2-0, -1-2 and found (2,2,-3) and then i did
(1/7) * (2,2,-3) = (2/7,2/7,-3/7). Is this correct? I feel like its not entirely correct.

Comment: In fact you should do (1/8)* (2,-2,-3) and add this value to (1,2,-1).

Comment: @Akatsuki I think he is correct about the 1/7, no?

Comment: I think the second co ordinate should be -2, because you have to subtract all in the same order. (3-1),(0-2),(2+1)

Comment: Just a small mistake of signs :)

Answer (score 1):

The line segment that joins two points $\boldsymbol P$ and $\boldsymbol Q$ can be parametrized as: $$\boldsymbol F(t) = (1-t)\boldsymbol P + t\boldsymbol Q, \quad t \in [0,1].$$  When $\boldsymbol P, \boldsymbol Q \in \mathbb R^3$, this takes on the form $$(x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (1-t)(P_x, P_y, P_z) + t(Q_x, Q_y, Q_z).$$  The value of the parameter $t$ also represents the proportion of the distance of the point $\boldsymbol F$ from $\boldsymbol P$ to $\boldsymbol Q$; i.e., $$t = \frac{PF}{PQ}.$$  So, in your case, we would simply choose $t = 1/7$ and compute $$(x,y,z) = \frac{6}{7}(1,2,-1) + \frac{1}{7}(3,0,2) = \left( \frac{6+3}{7}, \frac{12+0}{7}, \frac{-6+2}{7} \right) = \left( \frac{9}{7}, \frac{12}{7}, \frac{-4}{7} \right).$$

Answer (score 0):

You’re right that this isn’t quite correct—the “point” that you’ve found isn’t even between $P$ and $Q$, as you can see by looking at just the first coordinate. You’re almost there, though. When you subtracted $Q$ from $P$, you found a vector that gives the displacement from $P$ to $Q$. Multiplying that by $\frac17$ still gives you a vector, not a point. How would you use that vector to find the point at that displacement from $P$?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ${1\over7}$ of the way from P to Q you need to travel along the vector $\vec{QP}=(3,0,2)-(1,2,-1)=(2,-2,3)$. So your new position will be

P+distance travelled$\times$ unit vector along $\vec{QP}$

=P+${1\over7}\times$distance between P & Q$\times$unit vector along $\vec{QP}$

=P+${1\over7}\times |\vec{QP}|\times {\vec{QP}\over |\vec{QP}|}$

=P+${1\over7}\vec{QP}={1\over7}(9,12,-4)$

Answer (score 0):

$$PR=\dfrac{1}{7}PQ$$
$$(x-1,y-2,z+1)=\dfrac{1}{7}(3-1,0-2,2+1)=\dfrac{1}{7}(2,-2,3)$$
Then
$$x-1=\dfrac{2}{7}, \qquad x=\dfrac{2}{7}+1=\dfrac{9}{7}$$
$$y-2=\dfrac{-2}{7}, \qquad y=\dfrac{-2}{7}+2=\dfrac{12}{7}$$
$$z+1=\dfrac{3}{7}, \qquad x=\dfrac{3}{7}-1=\dfrac{-4}{7}$$

$R=\left(\dfrac{9}{7},\dfrac{12}{7},\dfrac{-4}{7}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Basically the strategy that you want to follow is, take the difference between each pair of coordinates (as you have). e.g. x-y. That is the distance between them. Divide that by 7. Then add that result to y. That gives you your final coordinate. Do that for all three dimensions and you have your answer. It is a good exercise to help you understand if you can try to visualize what these steps represent e.g. in 2 dimensions.